# Is connecting a laptop to a smart tv via hdmi better than chromecast with google tv?

Tags: hdmi

I have been starting playing on GeForce Now on my laptop. In the meanwhile I have also bought a new Samsung TV series 7, 2020, entry-level model (TU70xx).
I was planning to buy the new Chromecast with google tv, install  GeForce now on it and then just play with a compatible controller (e.g. a PS4 one) that I need to buy.

Would this set up work better than just running GeForce Now on my laptop and connecting the latter to the TV via an HDMI cable? I guess I should still use a controller or a blueetooth keyboard + mouse to play from the couch. I would play both multiplayer and singleplayer games.

Thank you and sorry for the basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much better to connect your laptop up directly.

Adding a chromecast into the equation adds an addition point of failure as well as potential lag (having to cast over wireless). However if you are playing games where lag isn't a factor (IE. Turn based/card games) the lag won't be an issue.

Comment: Thank you. So HDMI is better and cheaper. Then Shall I just connect a blueetooth controller or keyboard to the laptop, and not to the TV, correct?

Comment: Correct, direct input into the laptop will be better.